# Why does this stop a view controller from deallocating?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

### The Memory Leak

I spent the whole day chasing down a memory leak that was coming from... somewhere ... and I just found it.

Except, I don't know why it was breaking. And I don't know why my change has fixed it.

So I created a minimum breaking example to put on here in the attempt of clearing up why this is happening.

### The Setup

The storyboard is very simple. It contains a `UINavigationController` with a `rootViewController` of type `ViewController` and this pushes onto `AnotherViewController`.

[image]

### The Code

I have a protocol defined...

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
```

And `AnotherViewController` conforms to it...

```
class AnotherViewcontroller: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    deinit {
        print(#function, "Another View Controller")
    }
}
```

I added the `deinit` method to show what is happening.

The `ViewController` code is slightly more interesting, but just as simple...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                              animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation,
                              from fromVC: UIViewController,
                              to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        switch (fromVC, toVC) {
        case (is MyProtocol, is MyProtocol):
            print(" NOOOOOO!")
            return nil
        default:
            print(" Yippee!")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewController` **does not** conform to `MyProtocol`.

It becomes the `navigationController`'s delegate.

And implements the function to return an animation transition controller thingy. But in this case I just `return nil` as I don't want to change the animation.

Nothing complex going on here.

### Running the app...

When I run the app it opens with the `Push` button in the centre of the screen. I tap the `Push` button and get transitioned to `AnotherViewController`. In the console I have  `Yippee!`.

When I now tap the back button I get  `Yippee!` in the console again and get popped back to the first view controller.

> #### Note: it never displays the red apple . It never enters that case. All it does is check that both `fromVC` and `toVC` conform to `MyProtocol`.

Except, the `AnotherViewController` has not deallocated. **Memory leak here**. If I run the memory graph debugger I can see it still in memory.

### The fix ... ????

So, I found two possible ways to fix this... doing either of these will fix it.

First way... add `class` to the protocol. By changing the protocol definition to `protocol MyProtocol: class {}` it fixes the problem. It will still show the green apple  but now it will deallocate as normal.

Second way... don't ask the view controllers if they conform to the protocol. If I remove the `case (is MyProtocol, is MyProtocol)` from the switch and just leave the default then it will now deallocate the view controller properly and fix the memory leak. It doesn't change the behaviour. It still displays the green apple . But now works.

### Another bizarre way of "fixing" it

If I leave all the code alone and make `ViewController` also conform to `MyProtocol` then `AnotherViewController` will be deallocated as normal (except it now shows the red apple ).

### The question

So... why is this happening? It sort of makes sense about the class protocol bit as it now knows it is a reference type... but still not sure about why asking if it conforms is causing the leak?

And also... why is asking if it conforms to a non-class protocol causing it to leak?

### Other things I have tested

If you remove the `switch` and just use an `if` to check if they both conform to the protocol `if toVC is MyProtocol` then it still deallocates fine. It seems to only be if it's in the switch.

If I remove the check for the protocol but instead check for the class ... `case (is AnotherViewController, is AnotherViewController):` then this doesn't affect it either. It still deallocates as normal.

If anyone can shed any light on this I'd love to know what is going on here.

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you cycle through pushing and popping the 2nd view controller, do you keep leaking more and more instances of `AnotherViewcontroller` or only the last one?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, if I keep cycling the push and pop then more and more `AnotherViewController` appear in the memory graph debugger.

Comment: Seems like it could be a bug related to casting inside a switch statement: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15425. Presumably using `is` is performing a cast somewhere. Xcode 7 supposedly fixed this (as per the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html)), but maybe it's back?

Comment: Try separating the switch out in to two separate switches and see if that also fixes the problem?

Comment: @MatthewHallatt if I ask one or the other inside the case `case (_, is MyProtocol):` or vice versa then it fixes it.

Comment: Then I’d imagine this bug is back? Or they fixed it for class protocols only?

Comment: @MatthewHallatt nice. Haha. I’ll file a radar tomorrow.

Comment: @MatthewHallatt in fact. Looking at the memory graph debugger. There is a leaked view controller with no references to it so it looks exactly like this bug.

Comment: Radar filed... http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4958673809965056